# How to get the email address of the person submitted the comment

Tags: 2011, content-delivery, ugc

I can get the name and id of the user who submitted the comment as

```
<ugc:ForEachComment runat="server">
<ugc:ContextVariable runat="server" Var="ugcComment.user.name"/>  // working
<ugc:ContextVariable runat="server" Var="ugcComment.user.id"/>    // working
<ugc:ContextVariable runat="server" Var="ugcComment.user.email"/>  // not working (displaying "Tridion.ContentDelivery.UGC.Web.Model.User" instead of email address)
</ugc:ForEachComment>
```

but not able to get the email address of the person.
The email address is stored in the UGC_USERS table of UGC database.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try using `emailAddress` instead of `email`:

```
<ugc:ContextVariable runat="server" Var="ugcComment.user.emailAddress"/>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried using <ugc:ContextVariable runat="server" Var="ugcComment.user.email"/> and <ugc:ContextVariable runat="server" Var="ugcComment.user.emailaddress"/> but did not get the email address of the user. Now realised that "A" in emailAddress is case sensitive. Thanks. It is working fine.